# How to count messages in socket before reading?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Please see following Python code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #udp Socket
sock.bind(('', 5505)) # bind port 5505
time.sleep(60) # waiting 60 seconds
countMessages = 0 # set counter to 0
while True:
    try:
        resp = sock.recv(2048).decode('utf-8') # read data from socket
        countMessages += 1 # and count messages
    except socket.timeout:
        return countMessages
```

When application is asleep I am sending `N udp` messages to binding port `(5505)` and then I reading and counting messages.

**How can I know numbers of messages before reading them from the socket?**

Comment: You might want to use [select](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets) to get your messages, add them to a pile and process them when needed.